# my one to many relationship is not working in sequalize model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models class and sections. A class can have multiple sections like for class 1 A, B, C section. These sections will come from the section model.

Class Model:

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Class extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Class.belongsTo(models.section, {
                foreignKey: 'sectionId',
            });
        }
    }

    Class.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            classId: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            className: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'class',
            tableName: 'Class',
            underscored: true,
        },
    );

    return Class;
};
```

Sections Model:

```
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class Section extends Model {
        static associate(models) {
            Section.hasMany(models.class, {
                foreignKey: 'sectionId',
            });
        }
    }

    Section.init(
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
            },
            sectionName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            modelName: 'section',
            tableName: 'Section',
            underscored: false,
        },
    );

    return Section;
};
```

Function:

```
    async getClasses() {
        const classes = await Class.findAll({
            include: [models.section]
          });
        return classes;
    }
```

getting this output: I want in same class there will be multiples sections, but I am getting separate objects.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "className": "Class 1",
      "sectionId": 1,
      "section": {
        "id": 1,
        "sectionName": "A",
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "className": "Class 1",
      "sectionId": 2,
      "section": {
        "id": 2,
        "sectionName": "B",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "result": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "classId": "1",
        "className": "Class 1",
        "sectionId": 1,
        "section": {
          "id": 1,
          "sectionName": "A",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "sectionName": "B",

          }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the relationship `1 class - N sections` then you should reverse your associations: a section should have a field like `classId` that point to a certain class (in other words many sections can have the same classId):

```js
Class.hasMany(models.section, {
                foreignKey: 'classId',
            });
Section.belongsTo(models.class, {
                foreignKey: 'classId',
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there any alternative solution? without adding classId in the section model?

Comment: or there will be many to many relationships instead one to many?

Comment: If one section should be linked to one and only one class then yes you should have 1:N relationship and so the `classId` field in the section model/table.